# dataClasses name in tooltip through formatter function [Highcharts]

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I did a pollution table based on a heat map chart, the tooltip use formatter function. I would like to know how can I make the tooltip to show the different categories of data (dataClasses name in colorAxis)  when hover the mouse (ex: Norma, Regular, etc..) instead of showing the values, like it does now ( 90 µg/m³, 220 µg/m³, etc...)

Here's the table: https://jsfiddle.net/Ruloco/58q60968/

Here's the tooltip code:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b><br><b>' + this.point.value + '</b> µg/m³ <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
                                }
              },
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a point's data class name via `this.series.colorAxis.dataClasses[this.point.dataClass].name`.

```
  tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b><br><b>' + 
                this.series.colorAxis.dataClasses[this.point.dataClass].name + '</b><br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
        }
    },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/58q60968/6/